# what Causes the ThreadPoolExecutor to throw Out of Memory and RejectedExecutionException?

Tags: multithreading, exception, out-of-memory

Ok it seems crazy somehow but

1. I need the ThreadPoolExecutor to throw Out of Memory for
   experimental stuff
2. I need the ThreadPoolExecutor to throw  RejectedExecutionException
   for experimental stuff

I tried to play with heap size , thread pool size and size of bounded LinkedBlockingQueue but it seems the computer try to avoid these two exception even if the maximum heap size is 512Mb. The input are large ontologies.

```
BlockingQueue<Runnable> workQueue = new LinkedBlockingQueue<>();
          //RejectedTaskHandler handler=new RejectedTaskHandler(); 
          ThreadPoolExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolExecutor(
                              numThread, //corePoolSize
                              Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors(),    //maximumPoolSize
                              0L,
                              TimeUnit.SECONDS,
                              workQueue
                             
                              );
```

here's the loop of submitting tasks :

```
while(indexThread1<list1.getThreadNumforAxioms(numThread, axioms1))
                {
                    executor.submit(new RunTask(reasoner, manager, list1, groups.get(indexThread1), 1));

                    indexThread1++;
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this:

- use a small thread pool (let's say maxPoolSize=10)
- use "java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue"
- create a task (Runnable) which execute a sleep()
- run a infinite while loop to submit above tasks to thread pool, catch the RejectedExecutionException
- set a small max-heap size (may be 200 or 300Mb)

you will see that as soon as the worker threads are exhausted, the thread pool will reject the subsequent task and the memory will startup filling with Exception objects... which will soon lead to OOM.